# How to run script on first boot?

Tags: linux, centos, boot, start, runlevel

I need to run some bash script only once on first boot (after OS installation) of my CentOS machine
This script should run **before** network service start (because this script will change network configuration)
How can I register my script to run before network service start?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the "chkconfig" line of /etc/init.d/network you'll see that the network has a start priority of "10".

```
/etc/init.d/yourscript:
#!/bin/bash
#
# yourscript  short description
# 
# chkconfig: 2345 9 20
# description: long description

case "$1" in
  start)
    Do your thing !!!
    chkconfig yourscript off
  ;;
  stop|status|restart|reload|force-reload)
    # do nothing
  ;;
esac
```

Then run `chkconfig yourscript on` to get it to run at boot.  The `chkconfig yourscript off` inside the script should disable it running on any subsequent boots.

Some versions of CentOS/RHEL/Fedora have a "firstboot" program you could try to use, but that seems like a pain.

You sure you can't run your network reconfiguration script inside of a %post in a kickstart? That's what I do.

Comment: +1 for the more "distribution-correct" methods outlined here.

Comment: I cannot use %post section in a kickstart file because I need it for embedded system: I'm creating an OS image with my application and distributing it. My network configuration is depends on MAC addresses as a result I need to do my first time configuration on the first boot. I'm going to try your solution using chkconfig. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: Stick it in `/etc/init.d` (symlinked to `/etc/rc#.d`) & the first thing it does is check for a file's presence: If the file exists the script has already run (so exit). If not, run the script and touch the file.

This also lets you delete the file to force the script to run again later.