# RHEL5 Run script on Server's first boot

Tags: redhat, linux, rhel5

How can I run a script on the first book of my rhel 5 server after install.

I am using post kickstart tasks to create a script and I'd like to run it the first time the server boots. How can I do this?

I'd like to use the "firstboot" service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason you NEED to use the firstboot service?

Take a look at: [How to run script on first boot?](https://serverfault.com/questions/247713/how-to-run-script-on-first-boot)

Answer (score 2):

Create a script that tests for the existence or absence of a file.  As the last step of a successful run of the script create/delete the status file.  When preparing your image, you need to make sure the your status file is in the correct state.

Comment: Also, the file must be in a place that generally cannot be easily deleted by users.

Comment: If the tasks you want to perform are really destructive you could simply have the script delete itself à la Mission Impossible, a 5 second warning is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo your scripts to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, and maybe find a script that will replace those lines later using cron jobs but the way to do it is `rc.d` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem; solved it by using the profile.d facility. In my case I had to be sure a file was present. If so then execute the file; after which I move the shell script from the profile.d directory to /tmp.

```
echo "Configure NVIDIA - xconfig."
cat << EOF > /etc/profile.d/configure_nvidia.sh
if [[ \$UID -ne 0 ]] ; then return 1 ; fi
if [ -f "/usr/bin/nvidia-xconfig" ]  
then
  mv -f /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bk
  /usr/bin/nvidia-xconfig
  mv -f /etc/profile.d/configure_nvidia.sh /tmp
fi
EOF
```

Jos Plas