# Kickstart Centos USB Key Centos 6.3

Tags: centos, kickstart

I have got an annoying issue when I try to use it using a USBkey install on a physical box that googleing is not helping.

The installation works fine if I specify a URL as install media, but it does not work if I specify the same USB Key as the install media. There is excellent discussion at centos forum
[Here](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=35505&forum=55) but it does not seems to help me.

First let me tell you what I indent to achieve, I need to have raid 1 using two hard-disk. The raid partition stuff works but I just can't make it work using a USB kickstart

if I give the URL it works

```
 install 
 url --url=http://my.machine/ks/CentOS-6.3
```

But with USB it does not

```
install
harddrive --partition=sda1 --dir=/
```

If I don't ignore that drive

```
ignoredisk --drives=sda
```

Then on later stage it says [sda1] not found. But if I don't ignore, it will install Linux on sda itself notwithstanding the fact that I am specifying disk names in raid conf

```
part raid.008001 --ondisk=sdb --asprimary --size=512
part raid.008002 --ondisk=sdc --asprimary --size=512

part raid.008017 --ondisk=sdb --grow --asprimary --size=200

part raid.008033 --ondisk=sdc --grow --asprimary --size=200

raid /boot --fstype=ext4 --level=1 --device=md0 raid.008001 raid.008002
raid pv.009001 --level=1 --device=md1 raid.008033 raid.008017
```

I am using CentOS 6.3 minimal install.

Comment: Why do your [virtual machines have RAID inside of them?](http://serverfault.com/questions/418019/is-it-necessary-to-have-raid-in-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: I don't use Raid on VM, it is for the Physical box. Updated the question to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easiest if you just make a new kickstart file.

Do the installation manually from the USB stick. The installed system will have a generated `/root/anaconda-ks.cfg` which you can then add your own customizations to. Customize and copy that kickstart file back to the USB stick and then run it.

Comment: Thanks for quick and simple solution. Any idea how I could add some script to run on first boot, or add some script in rc.local in the install itself.

Comment: @chandank Yeah... There's a framework in EL called [firstboot](http://serverfault.com/questions/299837/rhel5-run-script-on-servers-first-boot/299860#299860).